# Пропущенные элементы массива

Tags: массивы, математика, foxpro

Задача. Есть база данных абонентов. Лицевые счета занесенные в БД в разброс, например: 10, 15, 2387, 8888, 56713, 7130316 и т.д. Когда оператор добавляет нового абонента, то ему присваивается новый лицевой по алгоритму: максимальные значение в БД + 1. Но по логике вещей новый лицевой в этом примере должен иметь значение "1", т.к. его нет в БД.

Я придумал как сделать это с помощью SQL. Программа на FoxPro. Мой алгоритм: узнаю мак. значение. Создаю пустой курсор и заполняю его от 1 до мак.значения. І потом селектом выбираю те лицевые, которых нет в БД. Если результат не пуст - возвращаю мин. значение полученного результата, в противном случаем - возвращаю мак.значения в БД + 1.

Но а если вместо курсора заполнить массив от 1 до мак.значения (например 9999999), то он заполняется в десятки раз быстрее. Но только я не знаю как потом получить те лицевые, которых нет в БД. В PHP есть удобная функция array_diff(). Но я не могу найти аналог этой функции для FoxPro. Буду раз готовому алгоритму.

Comment: Это очень, очень скользкая дорожка. Одновременно с базой может работать несколько пользователей, и легко может получиться так, что два клиента получат один и тот же номер. Я не знаком с FoxPro, но наверняка в нем должна быть какая-то структура, поддерживающая авто-инкремент. Используйте ее для генерации номера, после генерации, проверяйте, что такого номера еще нет, а если есть - повторяйте генерацию. Так вы защититесь от конфликтов, связанных с многопользовательской работой.

Comment: ну при макс.+1 тоже самое. Вы за это не волнуйтесь. Мне главное как получить значение в середине массива.

Comment: Я о том и писал, что при макс+1 вы получите конфликт. Просто подход изначально неверный. Пусть вы получили в PHP все ID из базы и нашли незанятый. Но это не гарантирует, что он останется незанятым в тот момент, когда вы соберетесь писать в базу. Более того, поскольку параллельно может работать точно такой же скрипт PHP, он получит в точности то же (якобы незанятое) значение и тоже попробует записать его. ID должен генерироваться в базе штатными механизмами, предсматривающими атомарный инкремент.

Comment: Система автоинкремента существует в нашей системе. Вся проблема в том, что часто создаются новые БД путём переноса с данных с Excel или куда хуже Word. Где лицевые уже существуют. Часто возникают конфликты и для уникальности грубо добавляю, например +1000. Потому получаю пропущенные элементы.

Comment: Вы отходите от сути задачи. Проблемы добавление нового значение лицевого счёта при одновременной работе нескольких клиентов (операторов) давно решена. Не это важно в постановке задачи.

Comment: Создайте автоинкремент со значением 1 и получайте новый ID, вызывая хранимую процедуру, которая будет генерировать новое значение в цикле до тех пор, пока такое значение существует в таблице. Годится, если доля пропусков высока, по сравнению с данными.

Comment: Если пропусков сравнительно мало - создайте новую таблицу, заполнив ее порядковыми номерами, потом удалите из нее все имеющиеся ID из основной таблицы, пронумеруйте оставшиеся от 1 до *, после чего получение нового ID будет происходить в два этапа - генерируем новый авто-инкремент, получаем значение из таблицы идентификаторов по сгенерированному значению. Таблицу нужно подготовить один раз, генерация ID будет происходить, фактически, мгновенно.

Answer (score 0):

> В PHP есть удобная функция array_diff(). Но я не могу найти аналог этой функции для FoxPro

И не найдете ибо FoxPro, в отличие от PHP, не язык общего назначения, а СУБД и заточен на работу с курсорами.

Вы не показали код заполнения курсора. Но, возможно, что заполнив массив, создав пустой курсор и применив команду APPEND FROM ARRAY получите что-то более приемлемое по быстродействию.